# how loading a high quality video in python-opencv and play as normally?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('1440pHD.mp4')
while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "normally"?

Comment: when a load a video it plays frame wise or fastforward

Comment: Consider changing the title to: How to load a high quality video in python-opencv and play at normal speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to play the video at normal speed, you need to find out the frame rate or frames per second (fps):

```
import cv2
if __name__ == '__main__' :

    video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4");

    # Find OpenCV version
    (major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

    if int(major_ver)  < 3 :
        fps = video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print "Frames per second using video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS): {0}".format(fps)
    else :
        fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print "Frames per second using video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) : {0}".format(fps)

   video.release();
```

More details here: https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-find-frame-rate-or-frames-per-second-fps-in-opencv-python-cpp/

Then, instead of waiting 1 ms in waitKey() you should take into account the fps.

For example, if your video is 30fps, you need to play one frame for each 1000/30=33.333 ms. In this case, you should do approximately waitKey(33).

If you need better precision, you should keep track of the elapsed time (with the time.time() function) and the number of frames that you have played and keep adjusting the waitKey parameter accordingly.

If your video is playing more slowly than it should, you have to skip frames

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play a video in its normal play rate. The following function can help you to play the video in a normal way.

```
def readVideo():
    # Read the video 
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture("video1.mp4")
    # get the versions of cv2 and convert them to a python list [major_version, minor_version, subminor_version]
    versions = str(cv2.__version__).split('.')

   # check if the major version integer value is less or greater than 3
   if int(versions[0]) < 3:
       # if less fps will be equal to
       fps = capture.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
   else:
       # if greater fps will be
       fps = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
   while True:
       success, img = capture.read()
       cv2.imshow("Video", img)
       # On the waitKey() pass the integer value of 1000/fps as shown bellow
       if cv2.waitKey(int(1000/fps)) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          # quit the loop when q is pressed
          break
   return capture.release() and cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# call the function
readVideo()
```

**Good Luck**